# VS code newline adding tab instead of spaces

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am having trouble finding a setting for new line spaces in VS code. Currently, I have it set up to a tab is the size of 8 spaces (after detecting indentation from content). This is because a principal software engineer edits in a different program, and set tabs to be 8 spaces, but code inside brackets were only indented 4 spaces.

Is there a way to set new lines following a bracket opening to tab only 4 spaces, but keep the rest of my tabs set to 8 spaces?

I've tried resetting tabs to only 4 spaces, but that changes the document as a whole and the indentation is off.

For example, when tabs are set to 8 (after detecting indentation from content), this is what it looks like (I added a comment to show where hitting a new line brings the cursor to):

```
if ((access(LOGFILE, F_OK)) != -1)
    { 
        if(remove(LOGFILE) == -1) // Remove the older file 
    {
            //this is where the newline starts
        printf("Unable to delete the older log file.\n");
        return ERROR;
    }
}
```

Whereas, when I set tabs to 4, this is what it looks like (if statement indentation is bad):

```
if ((access(LOGFILE, F_OK)) != -1)
{ 
    if(remove(LOGFILE) == -1) // Remove the older file 
{
    //this is where the newline starts
    printf("Unable to delete the older log file.\n");
    return ERROR;
}
}
```

Is there a way to change it so I can use the 8 tab format (first example), but when a new line is created after an if statement, it'll only add 4 spaces? Normally. I would just reformat the whole file with a formatter and select those options, but that would make looking at changes when pushing to git nearly impossible, plus the other software engineer still uses the tab 8, spaces 4 system to edit.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You and your principle software engineer should get a code formatter and run it prior to pushing to git.

Answer (score 2):

Indentation is same in whole file,
you cant use two saperate indentation at once
simple solution will be: set your tabs to 4 spaces and use tabs 1 and 2 times whenever needed.

For reference: [Indentation | VS Code Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_indentation)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).